# Parsing JSON Help IOS

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking-2

I currentley have a jSON file which is created a by a script which can be seen here: http://ddelay.co.uk/bus/output.json

I currently have managed to setup the following to grab the JSON which works, i just cannot figure how to grab the data to assign it :/

```
-(void)makeStopRequests{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ddelay.co.uk/bus/output.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//AFNetworking Asynchronous Task
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation
                                     JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"JSON RESULT %@", responseObject);
                                        self.stopArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"stop_name"];
                                         [self.tableView reloadData];

                                     }
                                     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id responseObject)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
                                     }];
[operation start];

}
```

I hope somebody can guide me through how I would select the data,

Thank you.
Damien

Comment: Your code looks correct.  What is the output of your NSLog statement?  What isn't working?

Comment: NSLog Just shows the JSON from http://ddelay.co.uk/bus/output.json which is all correct, what I now need to know how to do is access the data, for example stop_name, or stop_number as when i try the objectForKey method it just returns nothing.

Comment: See my edited answer, if You want more clarification tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using AFNetworking and it provides you the response object. That is already being cast to Objective c object. 
You can simply assign it to NSArray or NSDictionary like this

```
NSArray *array = (NSArray*)responseObject;//if your json returns an array
NSDictionay *dict (NSDictionary*)responseObject;//if json returns dictionary.
```

This url returns JSON in this format;

```
[   {
        "service":"22", 
        "provider":"First in Yorkshire", 
        "dest":"Nether Edge to Woodhouse", 
        "dest URL":"/web/public_service_stops.asp?service=22&operatorid=31&systemid=30&goingto=Woodhouse"
    },
    {
        "service":"22", 
        "provider":"First in Yorkshire", 
        "dest":"Barnsley to Rotherham", 
        "dest URL":"/web/public_service_stops.asp?service=22&operatorid=31&systemid=30&goingto=Rotherham"
    }
]
```

Which actually is an array of dictionaries so to access data you have to loop like this.

```
NSArray *jsonResponse = (NSArray*)responseObject;
for (NSDictionary *dic in jsonResponse){
NSString *service = [dic valueForKey:@"service"];
NSString *provider = [dic valueForKey:@"provider"];
//Same for others
//It will better you create calss with these properties and then add that object to an Array, and on reloading data in table get that object from array in cellForRowAtIndexPath and use requried property to populate your data.
//Or if you just want to use stop name add stop name to array and use it.
NSString *stopName =[dic valueForKey:@"stop_name"];
//[dataArray addObject:stopName]; in case you want to use only stop name 

}
```

Comment: Ok, now you edited your answer to remove NSJSONSerialization, but you're just showing code identical to what the OP has already posted.

Comment: Yup because this is how we do it, actually AFnetworking return you casted object. id responseObject is objective-c object and will be dictionary or array depending on the json output. And we can tell how to get key value pair from that...

Comment: You can do the cast in the block definition, i.e. `success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSArray *responseObject)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just using something as simple as `NSJSONSerialization`, which is built into iOS after iOS 5 (may have been earlier, but not too sure).

Just get the data from the request and then parse that into a dictionary with the following code

```
NSDictionary *dict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
```

get the data using the standard built in networking structure as well

```
 NSURLRequest *someRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:someURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
 NSURLConnection *someConnection= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:someRequest delegate:self];
```

And then do whatever appropriate delegation and data processing. Read the documentation to get more details

Comment: I have attempted this using the code you sugested, but then when I attempt to use getObjectForKey@"stop_name" Returns unrecognized selector sent to instance. Can you advise please?

Comment: AFNetworking already calls NSJSONSerialization before the completion block.

Comment: you should be able to `NSLog` the returned dictionary, and see what it has in it to make sure it is getting filled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's minimal code:

```
self.stopArray = responseObject;
for (NSDictionary *stopDict in self.stopArray) {
    NSString *service = [stopDict objectForKey:@"service"];
    NSString *provider = [stopDict objectForKey:@"provider"];
    NSString *dest = [stopDict objectForKey:@"dest"];
    NSString *destURL = [stopDict objectForKey:@"dest URL"];
    // do something with this data
}
```

For anything more complex than this, you'll probably want to make your own data class, so you don't have to parse through dictionaries and arrays in your table view delegate methods.